# Functional Derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning, frechet-derivative

I want to know the steps involved for the functional derivative that has been taken for the below objective function

[image: Objective Function]

And the derivative for above objective function is give below

[image: Derivative]

These equations are from Generative Adversarial Networks, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00160.pdf  can be found on page 46 and 47. Please help me with the steps for the functional derivative of the objective function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's redefine the functional as:
$$
J[D] = 
-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{\text{data}}}[\log D(x)]
-
\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p_{\text{model}}}[\log(1 - D(x))]
$$
where $x,G(z)\in X$, so that
$$
J[D] = 
-\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_X \log(D(x))p_{\text{data}}(x)
+
\log(1 - D(x))p_{\text{model}}(x)\,dx
\right]
$$
Then the first variation is
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta J}{\delta D}
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial D}[\log(D(x))p_{\text{data}}(x)]
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial D}[\log(1 - D(x))p_{\text{model}}(x)] \\[2mm]
&=
-\frac{1}{2}\left[
\frac{p_{\text{data}}(x)(1-D(x)) - D(x)p_{\text{model}}(x)}{D(x)(1-D(x))}
\right]
\end{align}
We want $D^*(x)$ such that the first variation vanishes. Hence:
$$
p_{\text{data}}(x)(1-D^*(x)) - D^*(x)p_{\text{model}}(x) = 0
$$
Therefore:
$$
D^*(x) = \frac{p_{\text{data}}(x)}{p_{\text{data}}(x) + p_{\text{model}}(x)}
$$

Comment: noob here, why can you get rid of the integral with the first variation?

Comment: @vega for a functional $J[f]=\int_I \mathcal{L}[x,f(x),f'(x)]\,dx$, the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is $$\frac{\delta J}{\delta f} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial f_x}$$ (see the link). Here there is no derivative dependence though, so the second term doesn't show up. For a formal reason why... that's a separate question probably :)

Comment: Interesting. This is new to me. So the objective function is a functional because the input argument is a function and the solution to the minimum is a function? I'm not familiar with calculus of variations, do you have a good resource to learn it? Like an online course, or a book? Something for dummies preferred :)

Comment: @vega Yes, the variational calculus is a generalization of calculus, where you look at minima/maxima in the (infinite dimensional) space of *functions* rather than vectors or numbers. It is sort of a subfield of functional analysis in that sense. If you're a programmer, you might think of passing functions around as inputs to other functions. A classic resource is the book by Gelfand and Fomin. The wikipedia page is not so bad (for once), as well.